# is there any way to include a counter(a variable that count something) in a loss function in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, gradient, backpropagation

These are some lines from my loss function. `output` is the output of a multiclass classification network.

```py
bin_count=torch.bincount(torch.where(output>.1)[0], minlength=output.shape[0])

dr_output = (bin_count == 1) & (torch.argmax(output, dim=1)==labels)
```

I want `dr_output.sum()` to be part of my loss function. But there are many limitations in my implementation. Some functions are non-differentiable in pytorch, and also `dr_output` may be zero which is also not allowed if I only use `dr_output` as my loss. Can anyone please suggest to me a way around these problems?

Comment: can you show us the `output` or the shape of the `output`?

Comment: shape of output is normally 64x10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correctly:

```py
bin_count=torch.bincount(torch.where(output>.1)[0], minlength=output.shape[0])
```

computes how many elements are greater than `.1`, for each row.

Instead:

```py
dr_output = (bin_count == 1) & (torch.argmax(output, dim=1)==labels)
```

is true if there is only an element greater than `.1` in the corresponding row, and the prediction is correct.

`dr_output.sum()` then counts how many rows verify this condition, so minimizing the loss may enforce incorrect predictions or distributions with more values greater than `.1`.

Given these considerations, you can approximate your loss with the following:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F

# x are the inputs, y the labels

mask = x > 0.1
p = F.softmax(x, dim=1)
out = p * (mask.sum(dim=1, keepdim=True) == 1)

loss = out[torch.arange(x.shape[0]), y].sum()
```

You can devise similar variants that are more fit for your problem.